# Как передать по нажатию на span из него текст в input по его id - JavaScript, jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

1. через цикл создаю `span` с `id` по номеру `list`.
2. добавляю list под input в form

надо, чтобы по нажатию на конкретный span, текст span перекидывался в input

`response['is_taken'] = ['some', 'some2']`

**html**

```
<script>
... some ajax code ...
    var list = ''
    for (var i in response.is_taken){
         list = list + '<span name="'+(response.is_taken[i])+'" id="'+(i)+'">'+(response.is_taken[i])+'</span> '
         }
    $('#ajax-service').after('<div id="ajax-service-list" name="ajax-service-list">'+(list)+'</div>')
... some ajax code ...
</script>

<form action="/orders/add/" method="post">
    <label for="ajax-service">Услуга:</label>
    <input type="text" name="one_form-service" id="ajax-service" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Добавить заказ</button>
</form>
```

если передавать просто, то `document.getElementById('inputId').value = spanId.textContent;`

***но как по нажатию на span, взять его id и передать в input?***

**UPD**

код внизу выдает ошибку:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at Object.success (?category=simple:135)
    at c (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
```

```
 for (var i in response.is_taken) {
                            list = list + '<span class="badge bg-secondary" name="'+(response.is_taken[i])+'" id="#service'+(i)+'">'+(response.is_taken[i])+'</span> '
                            }
                        //console.log("i: "+i);
                        let elem_input = document.querySelector("ajax-service")
                        let elem = document.querySelector("service"+i);
                        elem.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                                 elem_input.value = e.target.getAttribute("name");
                            });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67238130/9653855 изящное решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если элементов span не тысячи, то в цикле создать прослушивание событий

```
let elem_input = document.querySelector("ajax-service")
for (let i =1; i <= NumberOfSpans; i++) {
    let elem = document.querySelector("#span"+i);
    elem.addEventListener("click", function(e){
         elem_input.value = e.target.getAttribute("data-something"));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Добавить обработчик события `click` на весь контейнер и делать там что угодно.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const input = document.querySelector('input')
let length = 10
while (length--) {
  const s = document.createElement('span')
  s.textContent = `text${length}`
  container.appendChild(s)
}

container.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.nodeName === 'SPAN') {
    input.value = target.textContent
  }
})
```

```css
span {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<div class="container"></div>
```